# Create alphabetically ascending list

Tags: python, alphabetical

I want to create alphabetically ascending names like the column names in excel. That is I want to have smth. like a,b,c,...,z,aa,ab,...az,...zz,aaa,aab,....

I have tried:

```
for i in range(1000):
    mod = int(i%26)
    div = int(i/26)
    print(string.ascii_lowercase[div]+string.ascii_lowercase[mod])
```

Which works until **zz** but than fails because it runs out of index

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
af
ag
ah
ai
aj
ak
al
.
.
.
zz
```

> IndexError

Comment: how many characters up do you want to go? Does it stop with `'zzz'`? Or are you after an `iterator`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

for i in range(1, 4):
    for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=i):
        print(''.join(x))
```

First, you want all letters, then all pairs, then all triplets, etc. This is why we first need to iterate through all the string lengths you want (`for i in range(...)`).

Then, we need all possible associations with the `i` letters, so we can use `product(ascii_lowercase)` which is equivalent to a nested `for` loop repeated `i` times.

This will generate the tuples of size `i` required, finally just `join()` them to obtain a string.

To continuously generate names without limit, replace the `for` loop with `while`:

```
def generate():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        for x in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=i):
            yield ''.join(x)

generator = generate()
next(generator)  # 'a'
next(generator)  # 'b'
...
```

Comment: do you mean `for i in range(1, 4):`? because the way it is right now creates them up to `'zz'`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Sure, I edited it, thanks. In the end, this generic solution let the author choose the maximum length he needs.

Answer (score 4):

For a general solution we can use a generator and `islice` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import string
from itertools import islice
def generate():
    base = ['']
    while True:
        next_base = []
        for b in base:
            for i in range(26):
                next_base.append(b + string.ascii_lowercase[i])
                yield next_base[-1]
        base = next_base

print('\n'.join(islice(generate(), 1000)))
```

And the output:

```
a
b
c
...
z
aa
ab
...
zz
aaa
aab
...
```

And you can use `islice` to take as many strings as you need.

Comment: use 4 space indentations.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>import string
>>string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>len(string.ascii_lowercase)
26
```

When your index in below line exceed 26 it raise exception

```
div = int(i/26)
```

, becouse of ascii_lowercase length:

But you can:

```
for i in range(26*26):  # <--- 26 is string.ascii_lowercase
    mod = int(i%26)
    div = int(i/26)
    print(string.ascii_lowercase[div]+string.ascii_lowercase[mod])
```

### EDIT:

or you can use:

```
import string

n = 4  # number of chars
small_limit = len(string.ascii_lowercase)
limit = small_limit ** n
i = 0
while i < limit:
    s = ''
    for c in range(n):
        index = int(i/(small_limit**c))%small_limit
        s += string.ascii_lowercase[index]
    print(s)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
l = list(ascii_lowercase) + [letter1+letter2 for letter1 in ascii_lowercase for letter2 in ascii_lowercase]+ [letter1+letter2+letter3 for letter1 in ascii_lowercase for letter2 in ascii_lowercase for letter3 in ascii_lowercase]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer to this question provided on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100865/increment-a-string-of-uppercase-characters)

A slight modification to the answer in the link gives the following which works for an arbitrary number of iterations.

```
def increment_char(c):
    return chr(ord(c) + 1) if c != 'z' else 'a' 

def increment_str(s):
    lpart = s.rstrip('z')
    num_replacements = len(s) - len(lpart)
    new_s = lpart[:-1] + increment_char(lpart[-1]) if lpart else 'a' 
    new_s += 'a' * num_replacements
    return new_s

s = ''
for _ in range(1000):
    s = increment_str(s)
    print(s)
```